# rails 3.0 is triggering validation on create for a validation that was supposed to be update only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

we are upgrading from rails 2.3 to rails 3 and we have some validation on a model like:

```
validates_length_of :corporate_type,  :in => 1..255, :allow_blank => false, :on => :update, :if => Proc.new { |rra| rra.show_corporate_type? }
```

In rails 2.3 this only gets called on update, but in rails 3, it seems to be called on create, which breaks some stuff downstream... Can someone explain why this is getting called on create?

Here is the stack:

```
app/models/rra_agreement.rb:11:in `block in <class:RRAAgreement>'

app/models/foo_application_delegate.rb:29:in `create_application'
```

Line 28 and 29 are:

```
rra = RRAAgreement.new()
rra.save
```

line 11 is the validation line above

thanks
Joel

Comment: try this - 

validates_length_of :corporate_type,  :in => 1..255, :allow_blank => false, :on => :update, :if => Proc.new { |rra| rra.show_corporate_type? == true }

Comment: thanks, but that doesnt seem to help.

Comment: can you tell us what error exactly is coming up, the stack trace and info given takes us nowhere

Comment: So the problem is that the proc is being evaluated on create, it may be ignored , but in my case, it raises an exception. I rails 2.3.5 the proc is not evaluated if the :on doesnt match, but for some reason in rails 3.0.17 it seems to evaluate the proc regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is changed for rails 3, try this to call only on update,

```
validates :corporate_type,:length => {:on => :update, :min => 1, :max => 20 }
```

Comment: validates :corporate_type, :length => {:on => :update, :minimum => 1, :maximum => 255 }, :if => Proc.new { |rra| return false if rra.id ==nil;rra.show_corporate_type? }

Answer (score 1):

I would try do the following using `:new_record?`

```
validates :corporate_type, :unless => :new_record?
```

new_records? returns true if it is being just created, else false.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have a work around, its ugly, but it seems to at least let us move forward:

```
 validates_length_of :corporate_type,  :in => 1..255, :allow_blank => false, :on => :update, :if => Proc.new { |rra| return false if rra.id==nil;rra.show_corporate_type? }
```

This makes it just false if the id is not there,it should be there on update.